# Exergy-Immediate Surroundings and Surrounding

Tags: thermodynamics

What are the differences between Immediate surroundings and Surrounding in exergy? If a system loses heat to the surroundings, what does it actually mean in the exergy concept? I have done a mathematical problem on the exergy balance and destruction. In the question, the system loses 2Kj of the heat to the surroundings. But in the exergy balance equation, The X_heat_out = 0. I don't understand why it is zero. I am attaching the problem here.

[The problem link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AIINl4mwp1i709cjobA5nC8CDYoJVyEQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your question is about the energy concept.  Please state in words your understanding of this concept.

Comment: @ChetMiller Exergy can be transferred by heat, mass, and work. Exergy may be destroyed in the process.

Comment: @ChetMiller I have edited my question. The previous one was actually not that informative.

Comment: I find what they are doing there a little confusing too (referring to the heat transferred from the combined system plus surroundings as zero to a larger enclosing surroundings).  But their final equation in this section mades perfect sense to me:  $$X_{distroyed}=X_1-X_2-W_{useful}$$where the W is the useful work delivered by the combination of system and surroundings in the actual process.  So maybe they were just getting a little too cute.  Does this final equation here make sense to you?

Comment: @ChetMiller I understand the equation clearly, the exergy balance equation for the closed system. Exergy destroyed can be calculated by multiplying T with S_gen. If you look at the second method they take Q_surr = 2KJ
 But What I am not clearly getting is that surrounding where they take X_heat is zero. I am guessing that because they consider the extended system for the calculation of the exergy destroyed, could this mean that the heat was lost in the surroundings and it doesn't have any work potential.  So that's why it is zero? That thought has crossed my mind now. Please clarify this.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I just can't decipher what they are getting at there.